# Override templates of external app in Django

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to override the templates of an external app ([allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), installed in site packages). Unfortunately no advice i read worked.
I added the following to my `settings.py`:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates', 'allauth'))
```

and copied all templates ([this content](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth/templates)) to `my_project_dir/templates/allauth`. But when I restart the server and reload the page I only get the rendered templates from the original allauth app in site packages, not mine custom templates. Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I tend to figure out what's going on (with `DEBUG` set to `True`), is to have a view render a template that didn't exist, and look at the list of locations Django tried to load templates from (which will be included in the error page output).

What templates are the views trying to render? If they're trying to render `allauth/foo.html`, then you'll want to add `my_project_dir/templates` to your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting, not `my_project_dir/templates/allauth`.

Answer (score 36):

Check the `INSTALLED_APPS` order, the first template matched will be rendered.

With this in mind you can just add the template under the same path in a custom app.