# How to override external app template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-recaptcha

I tried overriding a `django-recaptcha` template without any luck. What am I doing wrong?
I am aware of [Override templates of external app in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918839/override-templates-of-external-app-in-django),  but it is outdated. Thanks!

**django-recaptcha file structure**

```
Lib/
--site-packages/
----captcha/
------templates/
--------captcha/
----------includes/
------------js_v2_checkbox.html
```

**my project file structure**

```
project/
----templates/
--------captcha/
------------includes/
----------------js_v2_checkbox.html
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

(1) In your settings, rearrange INSTALLED_APPS as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'project',
    ...
    'captcha',
    ...
]
```

since the template loader will look in the app’s templates directory following the order specified by INSTALLED_APPS, you're template will be found first.

or

(2) List project's templates folder in TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS'] as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
    },
]
```

Since, DIRS is searched before APP_DIRS, you're template will be found first.

References:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/overriding-templates/

### Another possible solution

I notice now that `captcha/includes/js_v2_checkbox.html` is included by `captcha/widget_v2_checkbox.html`.

I'm not sure about what happens exactly when `widget_v2_checkbox.html` is loaded from captcha module ... so I would duplicate the "including" `widget_v2_checkbox.html` as well into your project's templates folder.

You might also decide to copy the full "templates/captcha" folder contents into you project, for consistency.

Just keep an eye on possibile future changes of those templates when upgrading the captcha module.

Comment: Could this be because I am using both template folder in project root and app template folders to override templates?

Comment: To narrow down things, I suggest to set TEMPLATES[{ ...DIRS': [], 'APP_DIRS': True, ... and try again solution (1). Do you get any error with `python manage.py check` ? Does it work ? Please let me know, I will suggest more tests afterward

Comment: No errors after `check` but my Django seems not  to care at all...

Comment: I would check the order followed by Django in template folders navigation. One way to do this is: rename "js_v2_checkbox.html" as "js_v2_checkbox.html.bak" in both captcha and project modules. You will receive a runtime error, and having settings.DEBUG = True a detailed explanation of what happens

Comment: I added an alternative approach to my original suggestion .. have a look ;)

Comment: My project/templates folder is missing: https://i.imgur.com/gveTMJj.png. It's looking in my `company` and `home` apps...

Comment: I tried creating a new app with a `templates` folder. That worked. I have feeling `APP_DIRS': True` excludes project root `templates` folder....

Comment: As long as you list it in settings.INSTALLED_APPS, the project should be treated as an app. Is it a valid Python module ? Can you issue `python manage.py shell` and from there `import project` ? Does it work ? However, since you managed to solve the issue with a separate app, I guess your problem is over ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can I see the order of your `INSTALLED_APPS`? It could be that you are rendering `django-recaptcha captcha` templates before you render your own templates. To fix this you could move the the external app `captcha` last in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list.

Comment: There is no such app called `captcha` in my project. django-recapcha is in settings.py and called `captcha`: https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha

Comment: Can you make `captcha` the last app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list?

Comment: Do you have this in your `BACKEND`? `'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',`

Comment: Yep, I do have that

Comment: I have updated my question with my full `TEMPLATES `