# django-recaptcha and django-csp nonce not working together

Tags: python, django, recaptcha, content-security-policy, nonce

I am unable to get a django-csp's nonce="{{request.csp_nonce}} to show up inside of django-recaptcha's [js_v3.html file](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha/blob/develop/captcha/templates/captcha/includes/js_v3.html).

CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN=['script-src']

CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ["'self'", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/", "https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/" ]

CSP_FRAME_SRC = [ "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/" ]

I tried:

https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha/issues/101

[How to override external app template in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924414/how-to-override-external-app-template-in-django)

This is likely due to the templates being rendered within the widget. Widgets use the render as described in [FORM_RENDERER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#form-renderer). It then loads from the built-in django/forms/templates directory and then loads by installed apps. It does not include TEMPLATES DIRS directories.